# Getting Album Art for music player Android

Tags: android, android-music-player, albumart

I want to know the code (Function) how to return an image of the albumart in a musicplayer. Can you explain what parameters I should pass? I can pass the file path to the function.

```
imported required libraries

public class SongsManager {
    // SDCard Path
    final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager(){

    }
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());
                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try following:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(file.getPath());
byte [] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Tyr This**

```
 private  byte[] getAlbumArt(String uri)
    {
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(uri);
        byte[] art = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
        retriever.release();
        return art;
    }
```

Comment: How does your answer differ from the existing answer?

Comment: And it was asked 6 years back which was resolved  Guess he just wants to earn points.